# Flot Pie Graph Rendering Problems

Tags: jquery, flot

I was able to get going rendering data sets of time plots so I didn't think graph problems would be that much more challenging, but for some reason I'm having real trouble outputting this properly.

Json data :

```
[{"data":[
    {"label":"Times Appeared In Backpacks","data":45,"color":"#D9868C"},
    {"label":" All Backpacks","data":10919,"color":"#86b5d9"}]
]}
```

Created by

```
$json_data[] = array('label' => "Times Appeared In Backpacks", 'data' => $appeared, 'color'=> "#D9868C");
$json_data[] = array('label' =>" All Backpacks", 'data' => $total, 'color' => "#86b5d9");
$mergedData[] = array('data' => $json_data);
echo json_encode($mergedData);
```

Which is called by

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/whats/encode_pie_graph.php",
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: onOutboundReceivedPie
});

function onOutboundReceivedPie(data) {
  console.log(data);

  $.plot($(".graph_pie"), data, {
    series: {
      pie: {
        show: true
      }
    },

    legend: {
      show: false
    }
  });
}
```

At the minute nothing outputs.

Anything glaringly incorrect here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mergedData[] = array('data' => $json_data);
```

Turns out isn't necessary.

```
echo json_encode($json_data);
```

The data I have can simply be json_encode()'d to be read via ajax and accepted by flot.